# useContext error: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useContext(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-query

I'm fetching data with `react-query` and using `Context API` to make the fetched data available to other components:

**kitsDataContext.js**

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import axios from 'axios'
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const kitsDataContext = createContext();

//creates provider so content on the database can be accessible to all components
export const kitsDataProvider = ({children}) => {

    const fetchKits = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("https://localhost:5001/kitsDB");
        return response.data; 
    };

    //saves JSON data on "data" variable
    function RQKitsDB(){
        const { isLoading, data } = useQuery("kitsDB", fetchKits);
        return { isLoading, data };
    };

    return( 
        <kitsDataContext.Provider value={{RQKitsDB}}>
            {children}
        </kitsDataContext.Provider>
    );  
};

export default kitsDataProvider;
```

In another file, I consumed that data on a component, I also wrapped that component on the same file to make it ready to render on my `index.js`:

**SerumRow.js**

```
import "./row.css"
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import AddToCart from './AddToCart.js';

import { useContext } from 'react';
import { kitsDataContext } from './contexts/kitsDataContext.js'

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { kitsDataProvider } from './contexts/kitsDataContext.js'

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

//complete row with all the data from the database, also adds AddToCart button below every kit
function SerumRowNoProviders() {

  //consume context
  const { RQKitsDB } = useContext(kitsDataContext);
  const { isLoading, data } = RQKitsDB();

  return (
      <div className="small-container">
        <h1>SERUM PRESETS</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3 text-center">
            <img src="./images/WavSupply-Sidepce-Elysium-Loop-Kit-920x920.jpg" alt="Product 1" />
            <div>{data.aa[0].name}</div>
            <div className="priceReact"></div>
            <AddToCart />
          </div>
          <div className="col-3 text-center">
            <img src="./images/WavSupply-Sidepce-Elysium-Loop-Kit-920x920.jpg" alt="Product 2" />
            <div>{data.aa[1].name}</div>
            <div className="priceReact"></div>
            <AddToCart />
          </div>
          <div className="col-3 text-center">
            <img src="./images/WavSupply-Sidepce-Elysium-Loop-Kit-920x920.jpg" alt="Product 3" />
            <div>{data.aa[2].name}</div>
            <div className="priceReact"></div>
            <AddToCart />
          </div>
          <div className="col-3 text-center">
            <img src="./images/WavSupply-Sidepce-Elysium-Loop-Kit-920x920.jpg" alt="Product 4" />
            <div>{data.aa[3].name}</div>
            <div className="priceReact"></div>
            <AddToCart />
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*takes user to page with all available kits */}
        <h1><button type="button" id="show-more" className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">BROWSE ALL</button></h1>
      </div>
  );
}

//wraps SerumRowNoProviders() with needed Providers
function SerumRow() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <kitsDataProvider>
        <SerumRowNoProviders />
      </kitsDataProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default SerumRow;
```

Finally, I render it on the HTML:

**index.js**

```
const serumRow = document.getElementById("SerumRow");
root = ReactDOM.createRoot(serumRow);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
        <SerumRow />
  </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

The problem is that I am getting an **error** regarding useContext():

```
react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useContext(...) is undefined
SerumRowNoProviders@http://localhost:3000/main.b08a434d0e7255432ca0.hot-update.js:44:56
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22007:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25293:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26589:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11599:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11643:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11700:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31574:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30821:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30744:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30717:11
performSyncWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30409:38
flushSyncCallbacks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18439:26
flushSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30513:11
scheduleRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31880:18
./node_modules/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js/performReactRefresh/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33918:21
performReactRefresh@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33903:29
./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime/RefreshUtils.js/createDebounceUpdate/enqueueUpdate/refreshTimeout<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:807:17
```

Removing the `useContext()` call allows it to compile correctly, so it's clear that the error relates to that. I thought the cause was `axios.get()` not fetching the data quickly enough (as it is an async function).
so as you can see I used the `await` operator but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky.

The issue is that `kitsDataProvider` is not a component because of the the first letter `k` is not capital `K` (they are almost the same )

If you fix the import

```js
import { KitsDataProvider } from './contexts/kitsDataContext.js'

// ...

<KitsDataProvider>
  <SerumRowNoProviders />
</KitsDataProvider>
```

The context will be provided to `SerumRowNoProviders`.

> React requires that the first letter of components be capitalized

Answer (score 1):

you can try to move the context provider to wrap `SerumRow.js` component inside `index.js` inside `React.StrictMode` wrapper